# sets and rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The `ChooseElements` Component renders list elements

depending of the state of each list item the item gets displayed differently

The `toggleItem` function sets for each element a new state if a clicked event occurs

why does using
`const selectedItems = new Set(activeItems)`

renders the changes immediately

but using `const selectedItems = activeItems`

the changes are getting displayed after a second re-render ?

```
export default function ChooseElements() {
  const [activeItems, setActiveItems] = useState(new Set())

  const toggleItem = (id) => {
    const selectedItems = new Set(activeItems)
    if (selectedItems.has(id)) {
      selectedItems.delete(id)
    } else {
      selectedItems.add(id)
      console.log(selectedItems.add(id))
    }
    setActiveItems(selectedItems)
  }

  const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) => (
    <ListItem
      key={object.id.toString()}
      value={object.Element}
      isActive={activeItems.has(object.id)}
      clickItem={() => toggleItem(object.id)}
    />
  ))

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(activeItems)}>gets sets</button>

      <ul>{listItems}</ul>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          /*  with button click get all list items with specific class! */
          console.log(elementObjects.filter((o) => activeItems.has(o.id)))
        }}
      >
        get Elements
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

child component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import './styles/choose-elements.css'

const elementObjects = [
  { id: 1, Element: 'element-1' },
  { id: 2, Element: 'element-2' },
  { id: 3, Element: 'element-3' },
  { id: 4, Element: 'element-4' },
]

function ListItem({ isActive, clickItem, value }) {
  return (
    <li className={isActive ? 'selected' : null} onClick={clickItem}>
      {value}
    </li>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Every time you do `setActiveItems()`, react does check the value of previous state and current state.

When you use `const selectedItems = new Set(activeItems)` it creates selectedItems in new address space. And updating with this state therefore triggers a re render. (and in the other case, the address space remains the same)

I'd illustrate further by this:

```js
const arr1 = ["foo"];
const arr2 = arr1;

arr2.push("bar");
console.log(arr1 === arr2); // new elements are pushed but address remains the same
```

I'd recommend you to read more about shallow and deep copy in JS and how react decides when to re render its component.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you are creating `activeItems` using `new Set()` so when you perform `activeItems.add` you are mutating your existing state. And react doesn't detect that you have updated it event if you perform `setActiveItems(selectedItems)`. Because `selectedItems` reference the same object as `activeItems` React under the hood just compare objects like references

`if (obj1 !== obj2) {//run re-render cycle}`

So you should create new Set when you are updating your state